# Laravel reset password

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, reset

I trying to do a reset password, my post route goes to ->

```
public function ResetPassword(Request $request) {
    $template_data = [
        'template'  =>  $this->template->ConstructArrayTemplate(),
        'token'     =>  htmlspecialchars($request->get('token')),
        'email'     =>  htmlspecialchars( $request->get('email'))
    ];            

   $rules = [
        'token'                 => 'required',
        'email'                 => 'required|email',
        'password'              => 'required|between:6,100|confirmed|passpower'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    $errors = $this->sortErrors ( $validator, array('token','email','password') );

    if ( $errors ) {
        $template_data [ 'Errs' ] = $errors;
        $template_data [ 'template' ] [ 'page_name' ] = 'Reset password';

        return view('reset_password', $template_data);
    }           

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token');

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $stats = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    });

    switch ($stats) {
        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return rediect('');
        default:
            return view('404');
    }             
}
```

The real error comes from:

```
$this->resetPassword($user, $password);

ErrorException in AccountSign.php line 109: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\AccountSign::ResetPassword() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of App\User given, called in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\app\Http\Controllers\AccountSign.php on line 137 and defined
```

I use ResetsPasswords, so, what he have?

Comment: The error is very clear, the `resetPassword` method expects a `Request` object, you are sending `User` and `$password`

Comment: check trait ResetsPasswords at reset function, I did same, what I should do ?